# Remove related fields in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have 2 txt files, both have lists of ip:port in it

i'm loading the lists into their own linkedlists

```
    public static LinkedList<DataValue> result = new LinkedList<DataValue>();
    public static LinkedList<DataValue> badresult = new LinkedList<DataValue>();
```

they have a class value

```
public static class DataValue {
    protected final String first;
    protected final int second;

    public DataValue(String first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

trying to make it so it does this...
loads list1 into result
loads list2 into badresult

then all badresult are removed from result

so loading is done

```
public static void loadList() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./proxy.txt"));
        String line;
        String args[];
        String first;int second;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           args = line.split(":");
           first = args[0];
           second = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           result.add(new DataValue(first, second));
        }
}
public static void loadUsed() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./usedproxy.txt"));
        String line;
        String args[];
        String first;int second;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           args = line.split(":");
           first = args[0];
           second = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           badresult.add(new DataValue(first, second));
        }
}
```

and here's my failed attempt at trying to remove all the same results from result linkedlist

```
public static void runCleaner() {
    for (DataValue badresultz : badresult) {
        if (result.remove(badresultz)) {
            System.out.println("removed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not removed...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: implement the `equals` method in `DataValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java we use the `equals` method to check for object equality. Your `DataValue` class does not implement this so when you ask to remove an object from the list it is actually comparing the object using `==` (as implemented by the `Object` class).

```
System.out.println((new DataValue("hello", 1)).equals(new DataValue("hello", 1))); 
// prints false
```

This is because the 2 objects are actually represented by 2 different spaces in memory. To resolve this you need to override the `equals` method in the `DataValue` class, it is also good practice to override the `hashCode` method as well. I used eclipse to generate the 2 methods for me:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((first == null) ? 0 : first.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + second;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    DataValue other = (DataValue) obj;
    if (first == null) {
        if (other.first != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!first.equals(other.first))
        return false;
    if (second != other.second)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```